# How to add a commit in current branch to change content to a specific commit in another branch

Tags: git

I have `branchA` and `branchB`, both of which are checked out from `master` branch.

`branchA` has commits `commitA1` and `commitA2` and `branchB` has commits `commitB1` and `commitB2`. Changes on both branches have overlaps.

I want to add a commit `commitA3` in `branchA` so that `branchA` and `commitB1` in `branchB` would look exactly the same without any conflicts resolving. How can I create `commitA3`?

```
master------------------------------------|
  |---- branchA                           |---- branchB
          |---- commitA1              s~~~~~>     |---- commitB1
          |---- commitA2 (current)    s           |---- commitB2 (current)
          |---- commitA3 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~s
```

Comment: usually thing doesn't go like this, if you want to merge without conflict one of the branches should be merged with master then the other branch rebase with master.

Comment: @mamounothman this is not used in routine work, actually I would like to write a custom github actions, which exactly does this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is:

```
git checkout branchA
git rm -r .
git checkout commitB1 -- .
git commit -am commitA3
```

Here:

```
$ git diff master..branchA
diff --git a/y b/y
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..975fbec
--- /dev/null
+++ b/y
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+y
diff --git a/z b/z
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..b680253
--- /dev/null
+++ b/z
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+z
$ git diff master..branchB
diff --git a/w b/w
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e556b83
--- /dev/null
+++ b/w
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+w
diff --git a/z b/z
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..67d0c15
--- /dev/null
+++ b/z
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+z2
$ git diff branchA branchB
diff --git a/w b/w
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e556b83
--- /dev/null
+++ b/w
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+w
diff --git a/y b/y
deleted file mode 100644
index 975fbec..0000000
--- a/y
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-y
diff --git a/z b/z
index b680253..67d0c15 100644
--- a/z
+++ b/z
@@ -1 +1 @@
-z
+z2
$ git show-branch master branchA branchB commitB1 
* [master] master
 ! [branchA] commitA2
  ! [branchB] commitB2
   ! [commitB1] commitB1
----
  +  [branchB] commitB2
  ++ [commitB1] commitB1
 +   [branchA] commitA2
 +   [branchA^] commitA1
*+++ [master] master
$ git checkout branchA
Switched to branch 'branchA'
$ git rm -r .
rm 'x'
rm 'y'
rm 'z'
$ git checkout commitB1 -- .
$ git commit -am commitA3
[branchA 3b1b4d1] commitA3
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 2 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 y
$ git diff branchA commitB1 && echo same
same
$ git show-branch master branchA branchB commitB1 
! [master] master
 * [branchA] commitA3
  ! [branchB] commitB2
   ! [commitB1] commitB1
----
 *   [branchA] commitA3
 *   [branchA^] commitA2
 *   [branchA~2] commitA1
  +  [branchB] commitB2
  ++ [commitB1] commitB1
+*++ [master] master
```

Answer (score 0):

In local repo, I can perform:

```
git diff origin/branchA commitB1> /tmp/commit_branch_diff.patch
git checkout branchA
git apply /tmp/commit_branch_diff.patch
git add -all .
git commit -m "commitB1"
git push origin branchA
```

In GH actions, I implemented (through cloning another repo):

```
execSync(`git diff origin/${branch} ${commit}> ${diffPatch}`);
execSync(`git clone --quiet --branch ${branch} --depth 1 ${origin} ${cwd}`);
execSync('git config --local user.name bot', { cwd });
execSync('git config --local user.email "<>"', { cwd });
execSync(`git apply ${diffPatch}`, { cwd });
execSync('git add --all .', { cwd });
execSync(`git commit -m ${commit}`, { cwd });
execSync(`git push ${origin} ${branch}`, { cwd, encoding: 'utf8' });
```